# Scilab xcos String Handling

Tags: matlab, octave, simulink, scilab, xcos

I am trying to build a model where the string is output. How to display string (as input and output) in Scilab xcos modelling. Is there any package that I have to install?

What I meant is the function that I am linking with modelling is returning a string. But Xcos doesn't support string parsing between two models and there is no palette to display the string (in Xcos).

Comment: Your question is too broad or confusing. You will get more interest if you show a minimial example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per my research, there is no palette to display the string in Xcos.
And also we can't parse the string as function output between two Xcos models.